# Rails - Show/hide CSS class when parameter exist in URL

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, parameters

In my view I've a form where I only want to show inputs when its parameters appear in the URL:

```
= form_tag search_path, :method => :get do
  = select_tag 'search[type]', options_for_select([['Publishers', 'publishers'], ['Editions', 'editions'], ['Contributors', 'contributors']], selected = (params[:search][:type] rescue nil)), prompt: "Search type", :required => "true"

  = select_tag 'search[filter]', options_for_select([['Filter by', 'filter_by'], ['All', 'all']], selected = (params[:search][:filter] rescue nil)), prompt: "Select filter", :required => "true"

  - invisible = params[:search][:value].present? ? '' : 'invisible'
  = text_field_tag 'search[value]', (params[:id] || params[:search][:value] rescue nil), :required => "true", :class =>  "#{invisible}", :placeholder => "Type search"
```

My idea was control it showing a CSS class called "invisible" with `display: none;`, as above. But when I render the view it returns this Rails error in the line where I declare the "invisible":

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you please paste your URL ?

Comment: params or params[:search] is nil ...

Comment: Not that I need the complete params list. please raise params.inspect in your controllers action and paste the result here.

Comment: This is the URL: `http://localhost:3000/admin/works/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Btype%5D=editions&search%5Bfilter%5D=filter_by&search%5Bvalue%5D=text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when the form is loading params[:search] is nil, and you're trying to call [:filter] on it, hence undefined method [] for nil.

There's various solutions, some nice, some not so nice, pick your favourite:

```
invisible = params[:search].try(:[], :value) ? '' : 'invisible'
invisible = params[:search] && params[:search][:value] ? '' : 'invisible'
invisible = (params[:search] || {})[:value] ? '' : 'inivisble'
invisible = (params[:search][:value] rescue nil) ? '' : 'invisible'
```

Comment: Thank you Mike! I used the last solution and worked. Sorry for the confusion, I misspelled the params in the condition, now it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `params[:search]` is `nil` and you are calling `params[:search][:filter]`

Try:

```
invisible = params[:search].present? ? (params[:search][:filter].present? ? '' : 'invisible') : ''
```

Answer (score -1):

```
...

- invisible = params[:search].try(:[], :filter).blank? ? 'invisible' : ''

...
```